# Display a PDF from a MemoryStream from ASHX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

What I need to do is;

1. Get a pdf from sharepoint
2. Get a single page, using PDFSharp
3. Return that to the view and display that page

What I have thus far is;

```
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";            
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=Something.pdf");

        // Get a fresh copy of the sample PDF file from Sharepoint later on
        string filename = @"book.pdf";

        // Open the file
        PdfDocument inputDocument = CompatiblePdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

        PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
        outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;
        outputDocument.Info.Title = "Pages 1 to 30";
        outputDocument.Info.Author = "Slappy";

        outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[1]);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        outputDocument.Save(ms, false);

        ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

What I can't figure out is how to then display that within the web page.

I have this;

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.media.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({ url: '/GetBookPage.ashx',
            success: function (result) {
                $("a.media").attr('href', result);
                $('a.media').media({ width: 800, height: 600 });
            },
            async: false
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="media">PDF File</a>
```

The above works if I save the pdf to the filesystem and then point the href at that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following handler:

```
public class GetBookPage : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string filePath = @"c:\somepath\test.pdf";
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
            context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            context.Response.End(); 
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I was able to get the PDF to display inline if you do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $('a.media').media({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    });
</script>

<a class="media" href="/GetBookPage.ashx?.pdf">PDF File</a>
```

The plugin is using the url (or more accurately the extension) to build the proper media container on the page.  If you don't have ".pdf" it won't work as expected.

Comment: I think you missed the point here a little or maybe I wasn't clear.  The PDF's I have in SharePoint are 100+ pages and All I want to return is the first page of each.  Hence the use of PDFSharp and returning a MemoryStream.

Comment: Sorry, Actually you gave the answer away with href="/GetBookPage.ashx?.pdf"  THAT was the silver bullet thank you very much!